# handling jquery draggable with php loop

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a php loop that creates a bunch of boxes populated with MYSQL data like this:

```
<?php
//display boxes
    while ($list = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $list['url'];?>">
            <div id="box"><h2><?php echo $list['label'];?></h2>
            </div>
       </a>
    <?php };?>
```

I want to make these boxes draggable with JQuery

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#box" ).draggable();
});
</
script>
```

This only allows the last box to be draggable because each time through the loop the div id is written to the newest div.  Any ideas how I can make them all draggable.  I assume I have to create a seperate div id for each box and then get JQuery draggable to recognize it but I don't know how to do this.

thanks!

Comment: put them in a class instead of id. Id's must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id`. Because you can use only one `id` per element but class can be used for multiple elements. Try this:

```
<?php
//display boxes
while ($list = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $list['url']; ?>">
        <div class="box"><h2><?php echo $list['label']; ?></h2>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }; ?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".box").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple identical id's! Change to class instead.

Example here: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gbk32/)**

php

```
<?php
//display boxes
    while ($list = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $list['url'];?>">
            <div class="box"><h2><?php echo $list['label'];?></h2>
            </div>
       </a>
    <?php };?>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
$( ".box" ).draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In one page you ID should be unique , So add a class instead of Id.

```
<div class="box"><h2><?php echo $list['label'];?></h2>
        </div>

<script>
$(function() {
$( ".box" ).draggable();
});
</
script>
```